# Create Employee Module like Customer module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I have created Employee module. same as customer module. i have copied all files from `vendor/magento/module-customer` to `app/code/Magento/Employee`. I replaced **customer** with **employee**. but it shows an error:

> 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Constant name is expected.

and

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>  There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

My `module.xml` is in `app/Code/Magento/Employee/etc` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Magento_Employee" setup_version="2.0.6">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Eav"/>
        <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

Please anyone tell me how can i solve it?

My **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeRepositoryInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\EmployeeRepository" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\GroupManagementInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\GroupManagement" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\GroupRepository" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\EmployeeInterface" type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\Employee" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\AddressInterface" type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\Address" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\RegionInterface" type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\Region" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\AttributeMetadataInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\AttributeMetadata" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\GroupInterface" type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\Group" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\OptionInterface" type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\Option" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\ValidationRuleInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\ValidationRule" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\ValidationResultsInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\Data\ValidationResults" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\GroupSearchResultsInterface"
                type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\EmployeeSearchResultsInterface"
                type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\AddressSearchResultsInterface"
                type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\AccountManagementInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\AccountManagement" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeMetadataInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\Metadata\EmployeeCachedMetadata" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\AddressMetadataInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\Metadata\AddressCachedMetadata" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeMetadataManagementInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\Metadata\EmployeeMetadataManagement" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\AddressMetadataManagementInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\Metadata\AddressMetadataManagement" />
    <preference for="Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeManagementInterface"
                type="Magento\Employee\Model\EmployeeManagement" />
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\EmployeeSession">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configShare" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\Config\Share\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="employeeUrl" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\Url\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="employeeResource" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Employee\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
        <argument name="employeeRepository" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeRepositoryInterface\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Helper\Address">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="addressConfig" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\Address\Config\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\Config\Share">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="employeeResource" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Employee\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapper\Composite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="propertyMappers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="employee" xsi:type="string">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Setup\PropertyMapper</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Model\ActionValidator\RemoveAction">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="protectedModels" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="employee" xsi:type="string">Magento\Employee\Model\Employee</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Address">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="employeeRepository" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeRepositoryInterface\Proxy</argument>
            <argument name="entitySnapshot" xsi:type="object">EavVersionControlSnapshot</argument>
            <argument name="entityRelationComposite" xsi:type="object">EmployeeAddressRelationsComposite</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\Address\Config">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\Address\Config\Reader\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\Visitor">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="ignoredUserAgents" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="google1" xsi:type="string">Googlebot/1.0 (googlebot@googlebot.com http://googlebot.com/)</item>
                <item name="google2" xsi:type="string">Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)</item>
                <item name="google3" xsi:type="string">Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Group" shared="false">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="groupManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Api\GroupManagementInterface\Proxy</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="SectionInvalidationConfigReader" type="Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="idAttributes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="/config/action" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                <item name="/config/action/section" xsi:type="string">name</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="fileName" xsi:type="string">sections.xml</argument>
            <argument name="converter" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Employee\EmployeeData\SectionConfigConverter</argument>
            <argument name="schemaLocator" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\EmployeeData\SchemaLocator</argument>
            <argument name="defaultScope" xsi:type="string">frontend</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="SectionInvalidationConfigData" type="Magento\Framework\Config\Data">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">SectionInvalidationConfigReader</argument>
            <argument name="cacheId" xsi:type="string">sections_invalidation_config</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Block\SectionConfig">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionConfig" xsi:type="object">SectionInvalidationConfigData</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Eav\Model\EavCustomAttributeTypeLocator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="serviceEntityTypeMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\EmployeeInterface" xsi:type="const">Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_Employee</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="serviceBackendModelDataInterfaceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Magento\Employee\Api\Data\EmployeeInterface" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Image" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="EavVersionControlSnapshot" type="Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="object">Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\VersionControl\Metadata</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="EmployeeRelationsComposite" type="Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="relationProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Employee\Relation</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="EmployeeAddressRelationsComposite" type="Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="relationProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Relation</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Employee">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="entitySnapshot" xsi:type="object">EavVersionControlSnapshot</argument>
            <argument name="entityRelationComposite" xsi:type="object">EmployeeRelationsComposite</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Employee\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="entitySnapshot" xsi:type="object">EavVersionControlSnapshot</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="entitySnapshot" xsi:type="object">EavVersionControlSnapshot</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">employee_grid_flat</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Employee</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="employee_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</item>
                <item name="employee_online_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Online\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="EmployeeNameHandler" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Handler\ConcatHandler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="concatExpression" xsi:type="object">EmployeeNameExpression</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="ShippingAddressHandler" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Handler\ConcatHandler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="concatExpression" xsi:type="object">ShippingAddressExpression</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="BillingAddressHandler" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Handler\ConcatHandler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="concatExpression" xsi:type="object">BillingAddressExpression</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="LastVisitAtHandler" type="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Handler\ConcatHandler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="concatExpression" xsi:type="object">LastVisitAtSubSelect</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="LastVisitAtSubSelect" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\LookupExpression">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="targetTable" xsi:type="string">employee_visitor</argument>
            <argument name="targetColumn" xsi:type="string">last_visit_at</argument>
            <argument name="referenceColumns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="employee_id" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">e</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="DESC" xsi:type="string">last_visit_at</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="EmployeeNameExpression" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\ConcatExpression">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="tableName" xsi:type="string">e</argument>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prefix" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">e</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">prefix</item>
                </item>
                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">e</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">firstname</item>
                </item>
                <item name="middlename" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">e</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">middlename</item>
                </item>
                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">e</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">lastname</item>
                </item>
                <item name="suffix" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">e</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">suffix</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="ShippingAddressExpression" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\ConcatExpression">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prefix" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">street</item>
                </item>
                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">city</item>
                </item>
                <item name="middlename" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                </item>
                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">shipping</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">postcode</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="BillingAddressExpression" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\ConcatExpression">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prefix" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">street</item>
                </item>
                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">city</item>
                </item>
                <item name="middlename" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                </item>
                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tableAlias" xsi:type="string">billing</item>
                    <item name="columnName" xsi:type="string">postcode</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Attribute\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Online\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">employee_visitor</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Employee\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Um...yeah. That's not going to be so easy. What exactly are you trying to get out? You should build it as a custom ORM model and module.

Comment: i am trying to create **Employee** module same as **Customer** module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this constant in `di.xml`:

```
Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_Employee
```

should be

```
Magento\Employee\Api\EmployeeMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 3):

mr.max,

Here is a solution for you:

1. Check, if you replaced the files taking into account lowercase and
   uppercase letters ("customer" -> "employee", "Customer" ->
   "Employee" etc.)
2. Check, if you changed file names and folder names, where there is
   "Customer" word.
3. Make sure you haven't changed any other words "Customer". For
   example, in the file

   ```
   vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/MassSubscribe.php
   ```

   there is a code

   ```
   $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customerId);
   ```

   That means that the method `subscribeCustomerById` is called from "module-newsletter" module (`Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber`).  And if you change its name to `subscribeEmployeeById`, you will get errors.